# How can I create a file in each folder?

Tags: linux

I want to create an `index.html` file in each folder of my project in linux.

`index.html` should contain some sample code.

How can I create a file in single command?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

```
find . -type d -exec touch {}/index.html \;
```

This'll create an `index.html` in `.` and all subdirectories.

Comment: In a lot of shells, the `{}` is expanded, causing the creation to happen at `/`. A better version of this would be
`find . -type d -exec touch '{}/index.html' \;`. Single quoting to prevent any shell-expansions.

Answer (score 4):

```
cd /project_dir && find . -type d -exec touch \{\}/index.htm \;
```

HTH

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you have a list of your project directories in a file called "projects.txt", you can do this (for bash and zsh)

```
for i in $(cat projects.txt)
do
  touch $i/index.html
done
```

To create your projects.txt, you can use the `find` command. You could replace the `cat` directly with a `find` invocation but I thought it more clear to separate the two operations.

Answer (score 1):

I know it's an old question but none of the current answers allow to add some sample code, here my solution:

```
#create a temp file
echo "<?php // Silence is golden" > /tmp/index.php

#for each directory copy the file
find /mydir -type d -exec cp /tmp/index.php {} \;

#Alternative : for each directory copy the file where the file is not already present
find /mydir -type d \! -exec test -e '{}/index.php' \; -exec cp /tmp/index.php {} \;
```

Answer (score -2):

The following command will create an empty index.html file in the current directory

```
touch index.html
```

You will need to do the appropriate looping if necessary.